# Uniqueness of affine forms

Tags: projection-matrices, multivariate-polynomial

Lets define the power symmetric group

$$\text{psg}_{n,d}(x_1,\dots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^d$$

And lets define a linear form as

$$\ell_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_i+a_{i0}$$

Where $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}$

For convenience, I'll drop the variables from the functions. I am searching for two sets of linear forms $\{\ell_i\}_{i \in [n]}$ and $\{p_i\}_{i \in [n]}$ where

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ell_i^d = \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i^d=psg_{n,d}$$

But there doesn't exist **integers** $e_1,\dots, e_n$ and a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ where $\forall i \in [n]~ p_i = \omega^{e_i} \cdot\ell_{\pi(i)}$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $d$-th root of unity.

According to the paper *Affine projections of polynomials* by *Neeraj Kayal* that was published in $2011$, this claim is true but I could not find an example of one myself.

Comment: Is it fine to take $\ell_i = x_i$ for all $i$? Then we only have to find the $p_i$'s.

Comment: Yes, we can take $\ell_i = x_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a simple example of this is $$x^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac45 x + \frac35y\right)^2 + \left(\frac35 x - \frac45y\right)^2.$$
More generally, when $d=2$, if we take any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^{\mathsf T}\!A = I$ (any orthogonal matrix), then $A \mathbf x$ gives us $n$ linear forms that will do the trick.

Comment: I have accepted this answer; so this is not part of the question but seems rather interesting that the numbers are Pythagorean triples and I was wondering if it actually relevant

Comment: For this to work, we need $(4/5)^3 + (3/5)^3 = 1$, so Pythagorean triples are only necessary to have rational numbers here. We could also take $\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{2} x + \frac{\sqrt2}{2}y\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{2} x - \frac{\sqrt2}{2}y\right)^2$, for example.